# Column name string rearrange in R

Tags: r

I want to rearrange the column names:

For example, the column names are `2009sum`, `2010sum`, `2011sum` and so on. I want change the names to `sum2009`, `sum2010`, `sum2011`.

I have tried the following code in R, but it's not working.

```
colnames(dataframe) <- gsub("(\\W+)(\\w+)", "\\2\\1", colnames(dataframe))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually not that far from the right and (most elegant) solution, which uses double backreference:

```
colnames(dataframe) <- sub("(\\d+)(sum)", "\\2\\1", colnames(dataframe))
```

Why does `colnames(dataframe) <- gsub("(\\W+)(\\w+)", "\\2\\1", colnames(dataframe))`not work?
Couple of things here:

- `gsub` is possible but is not necessary; `sub` suffices as you have just one match per string
- `\\W` is a negative character class for anything that is neither a letter **nor a number** (and an underscore) - wrong because it's the four digits at the beginning of the string that you want to match
- `\\w` (with lower-case 'w') is a positive character class that matches exactly what `\\W` does *not* match, i.e., it matches both letters and numbers and the underscore - wrong because what you want to match are letters only - not numbers

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response! I am very new to this. Your answer is extremely helpful!

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use this one:

```
vec <- c("2009sum", "2010sum", "2011sum")

gsub("(^[0-9]+)([[:alpha:]]+$)", "\\2\\1", vec, perl = TRUE)

[1] "sum2009" "sum2010" "sum2011"
```

Comment: Nice. This also works with `perl=FALSE`. Is there an advantage to `perl=TRUE` in this case?

Comment: That's very kind of you. Yes sometimes when I don't use `perl = TRUE` I get a weird result, but honestly I have to learn more about it.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple more ways:

```
x <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=3))

nam <- c("2009sum", "2010sum", "2011sum")
a <- gsub(pattern = "\\d{4}", replacement = "", x = nam)
a
#> [1] "sum" "sum" "sum"

b <- gsub(pattern = ".*(\\d{4}).*", replacement = "\\1", x = nam)
b
#> [1] "2009" "2010" "2011"

colnames(x) <- paste0(a, b)
x
#>   sum2009 sum2010 sum2011
#> 1      NA      NA      NA

colnames(x) <- sprintf("%s%s", a, b)
x
#>   sum2009 sum2010 sum2011
#> 1      NA      NA      NA
Created on 2021-09-22 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)
```

Comment: `sprintf` solution is really good that's a fantastic function.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
colnames(dataframe) <- paste0("sum",as.numeric(gsub("([0-9]+).*$", "\\1", names(dataframe))))
```

This renames your columns by pasting "sum" + the numeric component of your column names together, in that order.

Which gives us:

```
[1] "sum2009" "sum2010" "sum2011"
```

Dput:

```
structure(list(`2009sum` = 1, `2010sum` = 1, `2011sum` = 1), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```